# Android Inflating multiple layouts inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am working in a fragment. When the fragment is called it inflates a layout. Which all works.

```
 v = createTreeView( inflater,  container,  savedInstanceState);
```

On my action bar I have a search button which Onclicks changes the layout

```
btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
             v = createFliterLivstView( linflate, VContainer);
             count = 1;

            Log.i("Create","creating tree view kind of ");
        }
});
```

Both views work separately, but when I move the `createFilterListView` to the `OnClick` functions it does nothing. The Log has been processed which means it is running through. It just is not inflating the layout.

Below is the `onCreateView`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(  LayoutInflater inflater,   ViewGroup container,  final  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     linflate = inflater;
     VContainer  =  container;  


    m_Context = inflater.getContext();
    thisApp = (ThisApp)getActivity().getApplicationContext();

    v = createTreeView( inflater,  container,  savedInstanceState);

     FragmentActivity actionBar = getActivity();
     View d =  actionBar.getActionBar().getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.btn_search);
     ImageButton btnSearch = (ImageButton)d.findViewById(R.id.btn_search);


     btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
             v = createFliterLivstView( linflate, VContainer);
             count = 1;

            Log.i("Create","creating tree view kind of ");
        }
    });

     View b =  actionBar.getActionBar().getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel_search);
     ImageButton btnCancelSearch = (ImageButton)b.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel_search);
     btnCancelSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

                 v = createTreeView( linflate,  VContainer,  savedInstanceState);
        }
    });



    return v;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
private View  createFliterLivstView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container){
    View v1 = linflate.inflate(R.layout.list_main, VContainer, false);


    historyContainer = (FrameLayout)v1.findViewById(R.id.history_container_layout);
     FragmentActivity actionBar = getActivity();
     View d =  actionBar.getActionBar().getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.txtSearch);

    EditText filterEditText = (EditText)d.findViewById(R.id.txtSearch);

    filterEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            Log.i("anish", s.toString());
            historyContainer.removeAllViews();
            final List<String> tempHistoryList = new ArrayList<String>();
            tempHistoryList.addAll(historyList);

            for(String data : historyList) {
                if(data.indexOf(s.toString()) == -1) {
                    tempHistoryList.remove(data);
                }
            }

            viewStub = new ViewStub(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.layout.history_schedule);

            viewStub.setOnInflateListener(new ViewStub.OnInflateListener() {

                @Override
                public void onInflate(ViewStub stub, View inflated) {
                    setUIElements(inflated, tempHistoryList);
                }
            });

            historyContainer.addView(viewStub);
            viewStub.inflate();
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    setViewStub();
    return v1;
}
```

Below is the CreateTreeView

```
private View createTreeView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_symptoms, container, false);
    makeList();

    Button btnNext = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            String bsafe = thisApp.app_pref.getString("BSAFE", "0");
            if(bsafe==null || bsafe.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                thisApp.app_edit.putString("SYMTOMS", "");
                thisApp.app_edit.commit();
            }

            Set<Long> sel = fancyAdapter.selected;
            Iterator<Long> it = sel.iterator();
            boolean hasDone = false;
            int i = 0;
            while(it.hasNext()) {

                Long longId = it.next();
                //Log.i(TAG, "...id = " + longId);

                final Integer[] hierarchy = fancyAdapter.getManager().getHierarchyDescription(longId);

                // 5678
                WorkVO vo = list.get(longId.intValue());

                try {



                     pnObj.put("value" , jsonArr.put(vo.getName()) );


                    //i++;
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                hasDone = true;   
            }

            jsonSymptoms.put(pnObj);





            Log.i("Symtoms ", "      json="+ jsonSymptoms.toString());
            thisApp.app_edit.putString("SYMTOMS", jsonSymptoms.toString());
            thisApp.app_edit.commit();  

            if(hasDone) {
                if(bsafe!=null && bsafe.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                    mCallback.onNextWork(DefinedConstants.FRAG_BSAFE_REPORT);
                } else {
                    mCallback.onNextWork(DefinedConstants.FRAG_FATIGUE_RATING);
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please make a selection", 0).show();
            }
        }
    });

    TreeType newTreeType = null;
    boolean newCollapsible;
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        manager = new InMemoryTreeStateManager<Long>();
        final TreeBuilder<Long> treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder<Long>(manager);
        for (int i = 0; i < NODES.length; i++) {
            treeBuilder.sequentiallyAddNextNode((long) i, NODES[i]);
        }
        //Log.d(TAG, manager.toString());
        newTreeType = TreeType.FANCY;
        newCollapsible = true;
    } else {
        manager = (TreeStateManager<Long>) savedInstanceState
                .getSerializable("treeManager");
        if (manager == null) {
            manager = new InMemoryTreeStateManager<Long>();
        }
        newTreeType = (TreeType) savedInstanceState
                .getSerializable("treeType");
        if (newTreeType == null) {
            newTreeType = TreeType.SIMPLE;
        }
        newCollapsible = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("collapsible");
    }
    treeView = (TreeViewList) v.findViewById(R.id.mainTreeView);
    fancyAdapter = new FancyColouredVariousSizesAdapter(getActivity(), selected,
            manager, LEVEL_NUMBER, job_kind, list);
    simpleAdapter = new SimpleStandardAdapter(getActivity(), selected, manager,
            LEVEL_NUMBER, job_kind, list);
    setTreeAdapter(newTreeType);
    setCollapsible(newCollapsible);
    registerForContextMenu(treeView);

    manager.collapseChildren(null);




    return v;
}
```

Comment: Where's your createFliterLivstView function?

Comment: It is in a method that i call below the onCreateView

Comment: you have to post that as well so users can see why it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `createView` method returns a `View` which sets the view for the fragment. What you are doing in the `onClick` is creating a view that isn't overriding your fragments main view.

To be honest it would be much easier and would require less state logic if on click you replaced the Fragment with a new Fragment with the layout you wanted.

Having a Fragment that handles two separate layouts is harder to maintain and to keep the correct state. Not to mention will make the class much larger.

Comment: Thank you, for the answer. What I'm looking to do is have a main list that has categories and sub categories  `createTreeView` if the user clicks on the search bar it takes me to a new list that can filter list, Once the user has selected said item it should then select the item on the treeViewList. My question is is that something that can be done in 2 fragments?

Comment: If I am understanding you right you are trying to show different data in the list despite if the user is searching or scrolling correct ?

Comment: It is the same data but show in a different way. So the treeView means that can manually find the item by expanding the the view, or if they know what they want they can you the search bar to find that specific item.

Comment: So I guess my point still stands. When you create a `ListView` they have an `Adapter` of some type that is used to manage the how to show the data in the list. A `TreeListView` is a 3rd party view widget but it still works the same it has an `Adapter` which backs the `View`.

Comment: So I am not sure why you are trying to inflate a new list view itself. Are you trying to change the entire type of list view you are showing or the individual cells? Because if it is the latter you are not doing it right. 

You should override the `getView` method in your adapter and have it display a different layout for each cell depending on the data or state you have.

Comment: I see, thank you, I will have a look at doing the Override.  I would give you a thumbs up if I had enough reputation. But have a  +1. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Inflate a view with this method.

```
View v = View.inflate(m_context,R.layout.yourlayout,null);
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried it with not luck. I have seen through other post with the same topic that this is the correct method. However there must be a problem with the way I have set this up.

Comment: mark as answer if you got any helpful in my answer.

Comment: I can't yet as I do not have enough reputation. While it didn't help me I think in most cases that is the correct answer. +1